# C# Regex to extract (n-3) and (n-2) character, where n is the length of the string

Tags: c#, regex

Need regex expression in C# to extract 2 digits from the last but 2 digits.

> For example consider the string "QWEREIA89RR". Here I want to extract
> "89"

Comment: It looks like you are looking to create a regex, but do not know where to get started. Please check [Reference - What does this regex mean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618) resource, it has plenty of hints. Also, refer to [Learning Regular Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736) post for some basic regex info. Once you get some expression ready and still have issues with the solution, please edit the question with the latest details and we'll be glad to help you fix the problem.

Comment: Also the [regex tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info) contains very useful information, specifically see "How to ask"

Comment: Thanks for references. The answer is (..(?=..$))

Answer (score -1):

Here is a approach with linq

```
string input = "Q1WEREIA89RR";
string result = string.Concat(input.Where(char.IsDigit).Reverse().Take(2).Reverse());
```

Comment: This answer suffers from the same problem as the one of @NitinS: "a1b2" will extract "12". Also, this does not answer the question for _a regex_.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman this case is not defined in the question. OP doesn't mention, the digits have to be coherent

Comment: So you need to request clarification

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I just make the assumption that digits don't have to be coherent - seems obviously to me and OP didn't complain

Answer (score -1):

use the regex `([0-9]+)`

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input = "Q1WEREIA89RR";
            var matches = Regex.Matches(input, @"([0-9]+)", RegexOptions.Compiled);
            if (matches.Count>0)
            {
                var all = string.Join("",matches.SelectMany(x => x.Value));
                int numOfChars = 2;
                var last2 = string.Join("", all.Skip(all.Length - numOfChars).Take(numOfChars));
                Console.WriteLine(last2);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer is not correct. For example, it will match "a1b2" with "12".